# How fast is Whoosh?

Tags: python, performance, whoosh, pylucene

Whoosh is a fast, featureful full-text indexing and searching library implemented in pure Python ([official website](https://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/wiki/Home)).

But I cannot find any speed / performance comparison to other search engine, especially Lucene based (pyLucene, Lupyne...) ?

I'm used to use pyLucene which is known to be fast but quite non-pythonic and not easy to handle (direct java-Lucene wrapper). There is a pythonic wrapper of pyLucene; Lupyne. However this is not convenient when core features of Lucene are needed.

Any performance hints between Whoosh and other would be appreciate.

Answer (score 11):

**{1} Whoosh vs Xappy/Xapian**

There are benchmarks for testing Python search supported by Whoosh and Xappy/Xapian [here](https://github.com/ThomasWaldmann/python-search-benchmark).

Whoosh Authors used those benchmarks to test whoosh against Xappy/Xapian [(ref)](https://github.com/whoosh-community/whoosh/wiki/Benchmarks):

**How the benchmark works**

> N documents are generated, the search word is a random word and 10 chars long, plus 10 extra fields with 100 chars of random stuff each (just to pump up the size of the document).
>
> For indexing, all fields are indexed and stored.
>
> For searching, all words are searched in random order and all stored fields are retrieved.
>
> For whoosh, we used the multiprocessing writer for building the index - this explains why it is faster for indexing than xappy (because it used all 4 cores, not just 1).
>
> For searching, xappy/xapian is faster (there was no parallel processing used).
> But you see that the speed difference between xappy and whoosh is maybe not as big as you expected.

**Index Size about 12MB**

```
# Phenom II X4 840, 8GB RAM, HDD
# Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) 
# [GCC 4.6.1] on linux2

Params:
DOC_COUNT: 3000 WORD_LEN: 10
EXTRA_FIELD_COUNT: 10 EXTRA_FIELD_LEN: 100

Benchmarking: xappy 0.5 / xapian 1.2.5
Indexing takes 2.8s (1068.9/s)
Searching takes 0.5s (6635.8/s)

Benchmarking: whoosh 2.3.2
Indexing takes 0.8s (3575.6/s)
Searching takes 0.8s (3714.8/s)
```